# How to troubleshoot when Chrome finds the page but Postman doesn't?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I'm faced by a condition that I've never seen before and can't really explain. Basically, I don't know **what** I'm seeing, which prevents me from concluding **why** it's happening, let alone **how** to kill it.

In my angular application I've added a route like this.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "beep", component: BeepComponent },
  { path: "**", component: LandingComponent }
];
```

The surprising part is that when I target it by the browser (*localhost:4200/beep*), I see the page rendered. However, when I paste the same post in Postman, I'm receiving the result below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <pre>Cannot GET /beep</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Does this behavior tell anything? If not, how can I poke the problem to diagnoze it further? (I didn't even know it was possible to happen...)

Also, when I run the page in Azure a 404 flashes and disappears. It looks like the original call ends (Not Found) and a new call starts (hence clearing up the Network tab. (I'm assuming it's the same issue that will be resolved once I get Postman working, though, so I'm not focusing on that.)

Comment: are you using proxy.config in your angular project?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the route. Please read my answer below.

Comment: @ChunbinLi Not entirely sure if I am but since I haven't explicitly set it somehow, I guess I'm not. Would that explain the behavior with failure when running in Azure while it works locally?

Answer (score 2):

Using a browser, you usually want to display a page (HTML). Using Postman you don‘t. Postman is there to send and receive data via HTTP by calling a service‘s link. So it‘s no wonder that your browser succeeds by calling this link whereas Postman fails.

An Angular Component is no HTTP-Service. And as your Component does not know how to handle HTTP-Requests, Postman does not get an answer and throws the error.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks for the explanation regarding Postman. However, Postman was only my clumsy way to diagnose the actual problem. The thing is that when executed in Azure, I don't get it to work (and it kind of resembled what's happening in Postman so I got mislead). Got any thoughts on that?